# efficient evaluation of max(a,b) inside loop c.f. branch prediction?

Tags: c, performance, optimization, architecture, cpu

What is an efficient way to calculate the maximum of 2 floats inside a for loop in C without using a logic statement which might stall the pipeline such as `a > b ? a : b`?

I am working with huge 3D arrays and have tons of loop iterations.

Comment: Why is the loop part of the question?

Comment: Also don't use `float` unless you have a very good reason to avoid `double`. Speed is only a good reason **AFTER** measuring.

Comment: @pmg Probably to justify the need for efficiency.

Comment: This is a good resource http://www.futurechips.org/tips-for-power-coders/basic-technique-to-help-branch-prediction.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check what your compiler outputs, it's probably "optimal" already. For instance,

```
float foo(float a, float b)
{
    return (a>b?a:b);
}
```

Compiled with GCC 4.5, `-O3`, generates this assembly on x86_64:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <foo>:
   0:   f3 0f 5f c1             maxss  %xmm1,%xmm0
   4:   c3                      retq
```

i.e. the compiler knows a lot about the instruction set you're targeting, and the semantics of your code. Let it do its job.

Comment: Awesome, I've verified this and it's true, however only when using the -O compiler flag. Omitting -O (whatever level) produces about 30 or so asm instructions. I learnt something new, thx

Comment: This works great for max but not a general technique to reduce branches.

Comment: @Aater Suleman: Checking to see what the compiler emits is a pretty general technique though.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't think this is faster than using branching but this seems to work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define FasI(f)  (*((int *) &(f)))
#define FasUI(f) (*((unsigned int *) &(f)))

#define lt0(f)  (FasUI(f) > 0x80000000U)
#define le0(f)  (FasI(f) <= 0)
#define gt0(f)  (FasI(f) > 0)
#define ge0(f)  (FasUI(f) <= 0x80000000U)


int main()
{
    float a=11.0,b=4.6;
    float x=a-b,y=b-a;

    printf("%f\n",lt0((y))*a+lt0((x))*b);
    return 0;
}
```

The defines were taken from [The Aggregate Magic Algorithms](http://aggregate.ee.engr.uky.edu/MAGIC/#Comparison%20of%20Float%20Values)